# $signed system task does not work with multiplication and addition

Tags: verilog

```
module main;
    reg [5:0] result;
    reg [3:0] a = -1;
    reg [3:0] b = 3;
  initial begin
        result = 0;
        result = result + $signed(a)*$signed(b);
        $display("%d", result);
  end
endmodule
```

The result is `45`. I'm confused because I think with the `$signed()` system task, I convert `a` and `b` to signed explicitly, and I think `$signed(a)*$signed(b)` will be `-3`, and the result should be `-3+2^6=61`. However, if I change `reg [5:0] result;` to `reg signed [5:0] result;`, it gives `-3`. I just can't explain.

Why does `$signed` not work?

Comment: Math operations in Verilog are context determined see: [math operations](https://sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2006-SNUG-Boston_standard_gotchas_presentation.pdf#page=16)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing signed and unsigned terms in the same expression.  You declared `result` as a `reg`, which means it is unsigned.

When you add the `signed` keyword to the declaration, then your expression only has signed types.  This is consistent:

```
0 + ((-1)*(3)) = 0 + (-3) = 0 - 3 = -3
```

`-3` is the correct result, and it is what you intended.  Stick with all signed terms/types.

Answer (score 0):

An assignment is an operator , just like addition and subtraction. Verilog has rules for evaluating the sign and the width of an expression and how all the operands and operators get interpreted *before* evaluating the expression. Although you have made the two operands of the addition signed, they are only 4-bits wide, but `result` is a 6-bit unsigned type. So the outcome of the addition needs to be extended by 2 extra bits. But since that is an unsigned type, Verilog 0-extends that value instead of sign extending it.

So you need to declare `result` as a signed variable, or cast it using `$signed` to get the intended sign extension out to 6 bits.

See the section in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) *Steps for evaluating an expression*.